# Read path out of textfile %username%

Tags: vbscript, path

I wrote a little script which is reading out a textfile that is located in a netlogon folder. In this file their are some paths in like `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Folder\`.

My script is reading the textfile and have to delete this folder.
The Problem I think is that the script doesn't know how to handle `%username%`. If i write `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Folder\` in the textfile it seems to work.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Dim folderPAth, objShell, objFso
Set objShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
folderPath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Folder")
Set objShell = Nothing

'To Delete the Folder
Set objFso = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject")
If objFso.FolderExists(folderPath) then
   objFso.DeleteFolder folderPath,True
End If
Set objFso = Nothing
```

The method 'ExpandEnvironmentStrings' will replace %USERNAME% with the actual username. Now you will be able to delete the folder.